Why does p5.js render colors differently when using point() in a loop vs rect()?
I'm working with p5.js to explore color rendering by creating a dynamic color gradient using the point() function. However, I've noticed that when I use point() to draw colors, they appear lighter or desaturated, compared to using rect(), even with the same RGB values.
I'm using two nested loops to create a gradient effect where the color dynamically changes across the canvas. Here's my original code:


function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 1000);
    colorMode(RGB, 255);
    
    //Draw a gradient using red and green values
    for (var i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 255; j++) {
            stroke(255, 0, 0); //blue fixed at 0, testing for only red, edited from 255,255,0 to 255,0,0 to show red
            point(i, j);
        }
    }

    translate(0, 300); 

    //Draw a solid red square using the same RGB values
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(50, 50, 400, 400);

    noLoop(); 
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>



p5.js version: v1.4.1
Browser: Safari, Chrome 127.0.6533.100
OS: macOS Ventura 13.6.1
I'm using Visual Studio Code with the Brackets extension pack for live view to run the p5.js sketches.
This screenshot shows an example of the color rendering issue with RGB(255, 0, 0).
What I've tried:

Setting a white background with background(255) to ensure no blending effects.
Verifying color modes with colorMode(RGB, 255).
Running in different browsers to check for differences.


If you put the line line(0,0,255,255) prior to the loops then you can still see the line through the red rectangle. The effect seems to be of some alpha component. I wonder if it has something to do with pixel density. In any event, for the gradient effect you are trying to achieve it might be better to use the pixel array rather than the function point.

Your code needs to set a minimum strokeWeight of  2. I cannot explain the Why part. Any lesser and it seems the color will not appear correct. PS: I suggest using pixels instead of vector shapes to make an RGB  gradient.


function setup() 
{
createCanvas(500, 1000);
colorMode(RGB, 255);


//Draw a gradient using red and green values
for (var i = 0; i < 255; i++) 
{
    for (var j = 0; j < 255; j++) 
    {
        strokeWeight(2); //# test by change to: 0 or 1
        stroke(255, 0, 0);
        point(i, j); 
    }
}

translate(0, 50); 

//Draw a solid red square using the same RGB values
stroke(255, 0, 0);
fill(255, 0, 0);
rect(50, 50, 255, 255);

noLoop(); 
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>



